# how to hide body content after the height of main div if body height is greater then div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a web page in which `.blocks` is `1000px` height and `<body>` is `2000px` i am using `overflow:hidden` to `.blocks` which is working fine but blank body is showing after it i want webpage height should be `1000px` only after that it will hide content.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  height: 2000px;
}
.blocks{
  height:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.block{
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with problem : https://jsfiddle.net/0b6g6886/2/

Comment: Why you need `height` on `body`?

Comment: here i am giving forcefully but there is a situation in my codes when body height is greater then inner div height..i am using app web view..

Comment: And what you wants to show in blank space?

Comment: i dont want that blank space thats why i want to hide the page after `.blocks` div....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
body{
  height: auto;
}
```